# Return confirm value from jquery .each function

Tags: jquery, function, each, confirm

I have a click handler on a button that uploads a file. It checks the contents of each of the cells of the first column of a table against a predefined value and only proceeds on user confirmation. I can get the below to work but it doesn't feel elegant. Any suggestions?

```
$('#upload').click(function() {
    var proceed;
    $('#mytable tr td:first-child').each(function(a, b) {
        if ($(b).html() == 'x') {
            proceed = confirm('u sure?');
            return false;
        }
    });
    return proceed;
});
```

**EDIT:**

I want to do something like the following i just dont know the correct syntax (and this doesnt work):

```
$('#upload').click(function() {
    return $('#mytable tr td:first-child').each(function(a, b) {
        if ($(b).html() == 'x') {
            return confirm('u sure?');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do the contents of the cell contain that you are specifically checking against?

Comment: the table contains a list of files that have already been uploaded. each cell is checked against the vlaue of the file selected through an <input type="file"/> control. The check is to make sure that users are aware that they have selected a file to upload that has already been uploaded.

Comment: I think what you are doing looks fine go with it.

Comment: Why are you maintaining the list of files already uploaded in a table, rather than storing the uploaded values in an array to check through?

Comment: Akkuma - you don't want to know. A fight between business users who want the list of files in a table plus the way the solution has already been implemented.... i've got an ulcer fighting this i just want to make this change in a way that is i know is elegant and right.

Comment: Can you do both? Keep the table, but under the covers store it in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to simplify your code at the very least

```
$('#upload').click(function() {
    //Get File Input Value
    var found = $('#mytable').find('tr td:first-child:contains(something)').length;
    var proceed =  found ? confirm('u sure') : true/false (depending on what you want to happen);

    return proceed;
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the modified code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/R5Mzt/ (updated to be more accurate)

I just ran a quick test in IE7, IE9, and Chrome and found the input's file value to be unique enough that it could not run into a contains problem. Both output C:\fakepath\nameoffile.png.

Comment: Alan is not looking for contains instead for a exact match so it will not help.

Comment: As I just edited and tested contains will work perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not looking to simplify just something elegant. I thought i could do something like in my edit

Comment: Since each() uses callbacks, you can't use the return mechanic to exit early (short circuit)--you have to use a closure like you did to pass the state back out. So your initial code is good enough, unless you want to do something like Akkuma offered here. For what it's worth, I would choose Akkuma's since it is a little more clear what is happening without having to decipher the code as much.

Comment: Thanks Akkuma - i've worked in your solution and it does actually read better.